# How to add hamburger icon to the right side of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` on which I can tap and hold a cell to reorder it:

```
class ToWatchController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    ...

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        ...
    }

}
```

But I would like to add a hamburger icon to the right side of my cell, to indicate to the user that the table can be reordered. Something like this:

[image: hamburger icon]

Is there some "default" way of doing this or I'll have to manually add a hamburger image on the right side of my cell?

Comment: In a table view, that is the standard icon shown when a cell is movable. Your link has nothing to do with that.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

Comment: If you really just want that icon on the right of a `UICollectionViewCell` why not just use a `UIImageView`?

Comment: Sorry, I reformulated the question. I'm already able to reorder the table, I would like to know if there's some property or something like that that I can set to show the icon (or if I have to manually add it myself)

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this, as there is with `UITableViewCell`.  The only way to add an image to your `UICollectionViewCell` is to add a `UIImageView` yourself.